# factory and controller dependency error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular js. I'm trying to make dependency between my controller and my factory. 
controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('MainViewController',['MainViewFactory', function ($scope, MainViewFactory ,$location) {

           //codes here

    }]);
```

and this is factory:

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.factory('MainViewFactory' , function () {
    var factory = {};
    //factory codes here

    return factory;
});
```

but on loading the page I have injector error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <link href="/public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/public/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/public/css/style-blue1.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_color"/>
    <link href="/public/css/jstree-themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/public/lib/toaster/toaster.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainViewController" >
<div id="navbar">
    <span> </span>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="tools">
        <button class="btn" ng-click="functions()"></button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="setting()"></button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="guide()"></button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="contactUs()"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="content" ng-view=""> </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/app/factories/MainViewFactory.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/app/controllers/MainViewController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

help me on this!

Comment: Controller and factory are separate files?

Comment: yes they are separate @Jasen

Comment: Your module is defined in `MainViewController.js` so reverse the order of loading with `MainViewFactory.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You should place the controller ahead of the factory script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/app/controllers/MainViewController.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/app/factories/MainViewFactory.js"></script>
```

You don't have to declare the same module again for factory, you just can define like this,

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('MainViewController',['$scope','MainViewFactory','$location', function ($scope, MainViewFactory ,$location) {

    }]);
app.factory('MainViewFactory' , function () {
    var factory = {};
    //factory codes here

    return factory;
});
```

Here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/eTuJsM1SWKjvSSFvrHzZ?p=preview)

Comment: If it be in the same file , yes U R right . but the problem is that I have separate files for controller and factory.

Comment: just change the controller like above and try, even if they are in different files , it should work

Comment: I did it before and this is that's error **app is not defined** @Sajeetharan

Comment: post your html or create a plunker/fiddle

Comment: change the order of script reference  according the way i have put